# How to have a language switcher that allows you to select the country and then the langauge within the country?

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

We are looking to have a menu at the top right that allows users to select the country they want to view and then once the country is selected, we want them to pick a language that they can view the site in. How is it possible and what are the recommended modules?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Language Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_switcher) module or [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module.

But as of now there is no contrib module that does exactly as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to built your own solution. there is not relation in Drupal between languages and countries.